# PHP multiple select form how to use: if (taskOption[0] is selected)

Tags: php, html

HTML:

```
<select name="taskOption[]" multiple>
    <option>first<br /></option>
    <option>second<br /></option>
    <option>third</ option>
</select>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
foreach ($_GET['taskOption'] as $selectedOption){
            echo "lesson:".$selectedOption."<br>";}
?>
```

This php code simply prints the selected options.

How can i separately do something if an option is selected ? for example

```
if (taskOption[0] is selected){
    $x="1";
if (taskOption[1] is selected){
    $y="1";
```

What i have tried with partial success so far is this:

```
$options = array("", "", "");
foreach ($_GET['taskOption'] as $selectedOption)
        echo "".$selectedOption."<br>";

        if($selectedOption == 'first'){
        $options[0] = "11";
        echo $options[0];
        }
        elseif($selectedOption == 'second'){
        $options[1] = "22";
        echo $options[1];
        }
        elseif($selectedOption == 'third'){
        $options[2] = "33";
        echo $options[2];               
        }
```

but i still have problem when i choose 2+ option..
(it only echo the last option)

Comment: First of all you have to add value attributes to all of options elements.

Comment: Then if you want to let user to choose multiple values add attribute 'multiple' to the select element: <select name="" multiple>

Answer (score 0):

You should add values to the options in the select tag first, so you can easy identify each one.

```
<select name="taskOption[]" multiple>
    <option value="one">first<br /></option>
    <option value="two">second<br /></option>
    <option value="three">third</ option>
</select>
```

After it, you should remove the "elseif" and simply do ifs for all

```
$options = array("", "", "");
foreach ($_GET['taskOption'] as $selectedOption)
        echo "".$selectedOption."<br>";

        if($selectedOption == 'one'){
        $options[0] = "11";
        echo $options[0];
        }

        if($selectedOption == 'two'){
        $options[1] = "22";
        echo $options[1];
        }

        if($selectedOption == 'three'){
        $options[2] = "33";
        echo $options[2];               
        }
```

Im mantaining your code but it can be improveed a lot. Im not sure why are you adding the values to an array ($options).

Comment: Also, You dont need to define an empty array with empty values,
$options = array("","","").

This works the same
$options = [];

Answer (score 0):

You should add the value attributes to your option elements

```
     <option value="first">first<br /></option>
            <option value="second">second<br /></option>
            <option value="last">third</option>
```

You are not wrapping your logic inside of the foreach.

```
 foreach ($_GET['taskOption'] as $selectedOption){
   echo "selected: ".$selectedOption;
    if($selectedOption === 'first'){
        $options[0] = "11";
        echo $options[0]."<br>";
    }
    elseif($selectedOption ==='second'){
        $options[1] = "22";
        echo $options[1]."<br>";
    }
    elseif($selectedOption ==='third'){
        $options[2] = "33";
        echo $options[2]."<br>";               
    }
    echo"end";
}
```

You need to put the swirly brackets around your logic to make sure everything beneath runs.